# Trying to fetch the list of products from json and then render it on the page in a React component. But don't understand what's wrong with my code

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function GoodsList(props) {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState(null);
    const goods = props.goods;
    let productCards = [];

    fetch('products.json').then(async response => {
        setProducts(await response.json());
    })

    let content;
    useEffect(() => {
        if (products != null) {
            for (let x = 0; x < products[goods].length; x++) {
                productCards.push(
                    <div className="productCard" key={x}>
                        <div className="productPicture">
                            <img src={products[goods[x].pic]} /></div>
                        <div className="productName">{products[goods[x].name]}</div>
                    </div>
                )
            }
            content = (
                <div className="list">
                    {productCards}
                </div>
            );
            console.log(productCards);
        }
    }
    )
    return content;
}
```

Initially I put the return of the JSX inside the useEffect function, but it was causing an error. Now it just doesn't return anything without any errors in the console, but the console.log inside useeffect outputs indefinitely somehow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's *a lot* wrong here, to be honest.  To name a few...

1. You're fetching the data on every render, regardless of whether you need to or not.
2. You're updating state on every render, which triggers a re-render on every render, indefinitely.
3. There's no dependency array in the `useEffect` call, so that also triggers on every render.
4. The component only ever returns `undefined` (the default initial value of `content`) so no actual rendered output will ever be seen.

Overall, the key changes to make are:

1. All of your rendering logic is in `useEffect`, but *should be* in the main body of the component to produce a rendered result.
2. The operation to fetch the data is in the main body of the component, but *should be* in `useEffect` so it only happens when it needs to.

So first let's wrap this in a `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch('products.json').then(async response => {
    setProducts(await response.json());
  });
}, [setProducts]);
```

So now this operation to fetch the data will only happen once, when the component first loads.  (And technically would happen again any time `setProducts` ever changes, but `setProducts` won't change since it also comes from a React-managed hook.)

Then after that, you seem to be *drastically* over-thinking how to build your rendered output.  Simplify.  Just return the JSX markup you want based on the state of `products`.  For example:

```
return (
  <div className="list">
    {products && products[goods].map((good, i) => (
      <div className="productCard" key={i}>
        <div className="productPicture">
          <img src={good.pic]} /></div>
        <div className="productName">{good.name]}</div>
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I would probably initialise `products` to an empty array rather than `null` too.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm just learning React and you helped a lot